# SQL Query Multiple dates to one date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a table `psttodo-uit` with some fields like `Hostess Code, Datum Bezoek 1, PA, PB, PG, GoedkeuringDoorNew, Blanco, ..` .

Now I would like to select all the fields where Hostess Code is equal to ... . I want an overview like this:

```
1 march  |   info     info     info
2 march  |   info     info     info
```

But in my table I have :

```
2014-04-03 11:32:18
2014-04-03 11:22:16
2014-04-02 16:05:22
2014-04-02 15:40:43
2014-04-02 15:17:41
```

So I would like to select for each day and make a count of the other fields like `count(PA = 1)`. Can I do this in one SQL Query?

Comment: The question is not very clear: Do you want to group lines by day and count the rows for each day? if so try `SELECT day(\`Datum Bozek\`),month(\`Datum bozek\`),year(\`Datum bozek\`),count(*) WHERE \`Hostess Code\`='your hostess code'\` group by day(\`Datum Bozek\`),month(\`Datum bozek\`),year(\`Datum bozek\`)`. for moreinfos see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html and http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select has to be something like:

```
select `Hostess Code`, DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M'), count(PA), count(PB), count(PG), GoedkeuringDoorNew, Blanco,... where ... group by DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M') order by DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M')
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DT, '%e %M')
, COUNT(PA) PA_COUNT
, COUNT(PB) PB_CCOUNT
...
FROM 
YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DT, '%e %M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Select DATE(date_column), col1, col2 
 from psttodo-uit 
 group by DATE(date_column)
 order by DATE(date_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by grouping the dates using the DATE() function and then count the conditions on the other fields using a sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end), like this

```
SELECT DATE(`Datum Bezoek 1`) as MyDate, sum(case when PA=1 then 1 else 0 end) as PA1, count(case when PB=2 then 1 else 0 end) as PB2, other fields here...
FROM yourtablename
WHERE `Hostess Code`=value
GROUP BY DATE(`Datum Bezoek 1`)
```